# Python logging how do i it create empty log file?

Tags: python, logging

How do I stop `logging` to create a log file when there is no log message? Currently, the logger has created an empty log when even no logging message to it. Use case is I created a `FileHandler` that only log error (by `logger.error("I am error!")`), but I don't want it to create a file when there is no error.

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/logging.html#filehandler) says to pass `delay=True` to create the file on the first `emit` call.